# Hilbert algebra definition clarification

Tags: operator-theory, definition, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Consider the following fragment from Takesaki's second volume:
[image]

In (c), we read that the involution $\sharp: \mathfrak{A}\to \mathfrak{A}$ is preclosed. What does this mean?

Comment: According to the definition here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeftHilbertAlgebra.html it means that $\sharp$ extends to a closed map. I suppose in this context, I guess this might mean that it extends to a continuous map from the completion of $\mathfrak A$ with respect to the inner product?

Comment: @tomasz Thanks for your comment! I really wouldn't know! That's why I asked the question, I encountered a lot of definitions so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Preclosed* is a (maybe somewhat dated) synonym of *closable* in this context. Here is a short crash course:

A (linear) operator $T\colon D(T)\to X$, where $D(T)$ is a subspace of the Banach space $X$, is called *closed* if the graph
$$
G(T)=\{(x,y)\in D(T)\times X\mid y=Tx\}
$$
is a closed subspace of $X\times X$. An operator $T\colon D(T)\to X$ is called *closable* (or preclosed) if there exists a closed operator $S\colon D(S)\to X$ such that $D(T)\subset D(S)$ and $Sx=Tx$ for $x\in D(T)$.

There are a couple of equivalent descriptions: The operator $T$ is closed if and only if whenever $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $D(T)$ such that $x_n\to x$ and $Tx_n\to y$, one has $x\in D(T)$ and $Tx=y$. It is closable if and only if whenever $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $D(T)$ suc that $x_n\to 0$ and $Tx_n\to y$, one has $y=0$.

Equivalently, $T$ is closable if and only if the closure of its graph $G(T)$ in $X\times X$ is again the graph of a linear operator. Every closable operator $T$ has a smallest closed extension, called its closure and denoted by $\overline T$, which is the operator whose graph is the closure of $G(T)$.

If $X$ is a Hilbert space, then a densely defined operator $T$ is closable if and only if $T^\ast$ is densely defined, in which case $\overline T=T^{\ast\ast}$.

In the context of Hilbert algebras, the relevant Hilbert space is the completion of $\mathfrak A$ with respect to the given inner product.

As pointed out by QuantumSpace in the comments, the involution $\sharp$ is not linear but rather anti-linear. The definition of closable and closed anti-linear operator is essentially the same.

Comment: Does the inner product extend to the completion of $\mathfrak{A}$? Or only the norm induced by the inner product?

Comment: Yes, the inner product extends to the completion (or, equivalently, the norm on the completion still satisfies the parallelogram law, which can be used to to recover the inner product).

Comment: So if I understand it correctly: Let $H$ be the Hilbert space space completion of $A$ w.r.t. the given inner product.  That $\sharp: \mathfrak{A}\to \mathfrak{A}$ is preclosed means that there exists a linear map $T: D(T) \to H$ such that $A\subseteq D(T)$, where $D(T)$ is a vector subspace of $H$,such that $T(\xi) = \xi^\sharp$ for all $\xi \in A$ and such that the graph of $T$ is closed in $H \oplus H$. Is this correct?

Comment: Some authors (e.g. Stratila and Zsido in the book "Lectures on von Neumann algebras" seem to require that the involution $\sharp$ is densely defined also (this is implicit in their definition of preclosed). Is this also here the case?

Comment: @Andromeda Your first comment is correct. As for your second comment, $\mathfrak A$ is by definition dense in $H$ and the involution is defined on $\mathfrak A$, so it is automatically densely defined. I don't know if Takesaki only preclosed for densely defined operators.

Comment: Oops yes $\mathfrak{A}^2$ is dense so $\mathfrak{A}$ as well...

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Here is a follow-up question if you have time/interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365185/is-the-operator-c-cg-to-l2g-xi-mapsto-xi-sharp-closable

Comment: @Andromeda That's not the point. The Hilbert space $H$ under consideration is the completion of $\mathfrak A$, which contains $\mathfrak A$ as a dense subspace by definition.

Comment: @MaoWao I think it is worth mentioning in your answer that the involution on a Hilbert algebra is not a linear map, but rather an antilinear map? Of course, the same things still are true (just replace the domain by the complexification of the Hilbert space for example, to reduce to the linear case). In other words, I believe Takesaki means that there is an antilinear closed extension of the involution.

Comment: @QuantumSpace That's true, I made a comment.